# Where is my .minecraft folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I cant find my **.minecraft** folder anywhere, i already went to **%appdata%** and roaming, and I also tried doing **%appdata%.minecraft** in run but I dont have it. Can anyone help me ? I play minecraft.

Comment: which OS do you use? I asume windows....

Comment: %appdata%/.minecraft  Note the /